# The Datastax cassandra community server 2.1.10 service on local computer started and then stopped

Tags: service, cassandra, cluster-computing

I am trying to configure a two node cluster with cassandra in windows r2 2008
So i installed cassandra community version in one server (10.xxx.0.1,10.xxx.0.2)
And then I stopped the service and then edited the configuraton.yaml file in the conf folder.

The changes are:

- cluster_name
- commented the num_tokens
- gave the tokens in initial_token,
- seeds as 10.xxx.0.1,10.xxx.0.2,
- listen_addresses are their respective ip addresses which are 10.xxx.0.1,10.xxx.0.2,
- rpc_addresses as 0.0.0.0,
- endpointsnitch as gossip

I also changed the cassandra rackdc.properties file to dc=DC1 rack=RAC1.

I then saved and started back the service and opened the cqlsh, but it is not connecting.  Below is the error:

> 2015-10-12 16:20:13 Commons Daemon procrun stderr initialized
>   If rpc_address is set to a wildcard address (0.0.0.0), then you must set broadcast_rpc_address to a value other than 0.0.0.0
>   Fatal configuration error; unable to start. See log for stacktrace.
>   ..

```
ERROR 21:20:14 Fatal configuration error
org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: If rpc_address is set to a wildcard address (0.0.0.0), then you must set broadcast_rpc_address to a value other than 0.0.0.0
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.applyAddressConfig(DatabaseDescriptor.java:285) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.10.jar:2.1.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.applyConfig(DatabaseDescriptor.java:443) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.10.jar:2.1.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.<clinit>(DatabaseDescriptor.java:136) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.10.jar:2.1.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:168) [apache-cassandra-2.1.10.jar:2.1.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:562) [apache-cassandra-2.1.10.jar:2.1.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:651) [apache-cassandra-2.1.10.jar:2.1.10]
```

Answer (score 4):

If you out 0.0.0.0 to the rpc_address you have to change the broadcast_rpc_address like in http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml_r.html , I think that the right broadcast_rpc_address can be the own ip address.

Comment: +1, if you don't have more than 1 ip address to deal with it is cleaner to set rpc_address to the sole ip address and to not set broadcast_rpc_address at all (comment it out), but either solution will work.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply, I changed the rpc_address to its respective ip's(10.xxx.0.1,10.xxx.0.2) in both servers, In 10.xxx.0.1 the cassandra service started but I was  not able to open the cqlsh and in10.xxx.0.2 the service itself didnot start